# Case Activities Hanging No Such FIeld

Tags: custom-fields, civicase, activity

I'm on Drupal 7, CiviCRM 5.57.2. Lately, I've been cleaning up a lot of custom fields in by deleting and adding new ones. I have one case activity type with 112 fields across three custom field sets (this is a workaround for +100 fields).

Anyway, when this case activity is being submitted, the logo hangs for a long time. I see that the Drupal logging indicates a DB error for no such field found. I cleaned up the cache and update the paths but the issue persist. Has the DB not fully deleted the fields?

```
$Fatal Error Details = Array ( [callback] => Array ( [0] => CRM_Core_Error [1] => exceptionHandler ) [code] => -19 [message] => DB Error: no such field [mode] => 16 [debug_info] => UPDATE civicrm_value_trac_72 SET `leave_1089` = 0,`what_is_the__1046` = '4',`what_is_the_youth_s_home_g_1047` = '7',`educational_status_1051` = '6',`if_yes_to_histor_1066` = '012',`does_the_youth_have_any_of_the_f_1067` = '01234' WHERE id = 1168 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'enrolled_in_a_job_r_1423' in 'field list'] [type] => DB_Error [user_info] => UPDATE civicrm_value_trac_72 SET `leave_1089` = 0,`what_is_the__1046` = '4',``what_is_the_youth_s_home_g_1047` = '7',`educational_status_1051` = '6',`if_yes_to_histor_1066` = '012',`does_the_youth_have_any_of_the_f_1067` = '01234' WHERE id = 1168 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'enrolled_in_a_job_r_1423' in 'field list'] [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such field" code=-19 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="UPDATE civicrm_value_trac_72 SET `leave_1089` = 0,`what_is_the__1046` = '4',`what_is_the_youth_s_home_g_1047` = '7',`educational_status_1051` = '6',`if_yes_to_histor_1066` = '012',`does_the_youth_have_any_of_the_f_1067` = '01234' WHERE id = 1168 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'enrolled_in_a_job_r_1423' in 'field list']"] )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the "Trac" custom field group in the UI does it still have the "Enrolled in a job" field? If so try deleting it again.

Comment: Error seem to go away for awhile. But note to others, it does prevent a civicrm upgrade which may or may not be related: "row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535."